Nginx Container Returning HTTP 302 for /metrics Endpoint Despite Allowing Anonymous Access
I'm running an Nginx container using Ansible and Docker. I have configured Nginx to allow anonymous access to the /metrics endpoint and set up a reverse proxy. Despite this, accessing the /metrics endpoint results in an HTTP 302 redirect to an authentication page.
Nginx Configuration:
Here's the relevant portion of my Nginx configuration:
# Loop through applications
% for app in nginx_apps %}
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name {{ app.server_name }};

        set $app{{ loop.index }} {{ app.container_url }};

        location / {
            proxy_pass $app{{ loop.index }};
        }

        location /metrics {
            allow all;
            proxy_pass {{ app.container_url }}/metrics;
        }
    }
{% endfor %}

# Dedicated server block for metrics
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    location ~ ^/metrics/(.+)$ {
        allow all;
        set $app_name $1;
        proxy_pass http://$app_name:8080/metrics;
    }
}

What could be causing the HTTP 302 redirect despite allowing anonymous access in the Nginx configuration? How can I ensure that the /metrics endpoint is accessible without redirection?
Allowed Anonymous Access to /metrics endpoint in my application

Since Nginx isn't set up to give a redirect, the redirect must come from your application, yes?

I have allowed anonymous access in my application for / metrics endpoint

You're not getting 403 Forbidden, so I don't understand why you think access rules are relevant

Basically it is directing to auth services , when I have allowed anonymous in my application which basically overrides all the authorization service in middleware
I was wondering , what is causing the auth redirect ... is it any revrese proxy error?

As I said in my first comment: There is nothing in your Nginx setup that'll cause it to give you a redirect response, so the redirect must come from your application.
